# Using mix of AND and OR clause in sails and waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I use OR and AND clause in Sailsjs and its ORM Waterline? For example I have a table of books

```
 _______________________________________
| book_name | author   | free  | public |  
 _______________________________________
| Book-A    | Author-1 | false | true   |
 ---------------------------------------
| Book-B    | Author-1 | true  | true   |
 ---------------------------------------
| Book-C    | Author-1 | false | false  |
 ---------------------------------------
| Book-D    | Author-2 | true  | true   |
 ---------------------------------------
```

I want to get Books by Author-1 which are either public or free,  which is Book-A and Book-B. How do I write this query with Sails.js

Comment: Do you mean "where either `public` or `free` is `true`"?

Comment: Yes, Book A, Book B and Book D all of them qualified for this. However Another condition is the author have to be Author 1, which failed for Book D. So the result should be Book A and Book B, In my question I typed it wrong I edited this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing so we can use the where api of Waterline, following is an example

```
Book.find().where(  { or : [ { free  : true }, {   public: true  } ] })
            .where( { author : "Author-1" }  )
            .exec( function (err, books) {
            //Books will be an array containing all the books that matches this criteria
            //Some code here
    }
```

Comment: Hi, just FYI,
multiple where didn't work for me on blueprint ?where={...}&where={...} .

But Jim's solution worked.

Answer (score 5):

The following query should also work:

```
const books = yield Book.find().where({
  author: 'Author-1',
  or: [{
    free: true,
  }, {
    public: true,
  }],
});
```

Comment: What if you **also** want to do an `or` on `Author-1` and `Author-2`?

Comment: Arrays act as "or" statements as well, so you could do: `author: ['Author-1', 'Author-2']` in the where statement

Answer (score 0):

```
  let booksResult=await Book.find().
                        where({author: "Author-1", 
                           or: [{ free: true  }, { public: true  }]
                        });
```