# How to add two or in one where?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

For example I want to create a query:

```
SELECT * FROM comment 
WHERE 
   text1 = 'test1' 
AND 
   (creator = 1 OR editor = 1) 
AND 
   (text2 = 'test2' OR text3 = 'test2')
```

How can I add second 'or' in object?

```
var where = {
    text1: 'test1',
    or: [{creator: 1}, {editor: 1}],
    // or: [{text2: 'test2'}, {text3: 'test2'}] // ????
}
```

I can't use chaining of find() because I create a query with where for REST API

Comment: Unfortunately that won't be possible until waterline v0.11 comes out when `add` support will be added: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/648. Until then you can use `.query()` or `.native()` depending on the adapter to do such query.

Comment: This other question/answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120258/using-mix-of-and-and-or-clause-in-sails-and-waterline